# setting the correct classpath for compiling and running Java packages?

Tags: java, compilation, classpath, javac

I have been using `Eclipse` lately, where `compiling` and `running` the program is very simple. Not much needs to be done in setting the `classpath`. But apparently that is not the case when it comes to running them from `commandLine`. when I try `compiling` from `terminal`, I am having various errors. I am pasting an image of `my package structure` of the project `cp125_soln`. Now I want to compile `Invoice.Java` in the `com.scg.domain` package,
I tried

```
javac src/main/java/com/scg/domain/Invoice.java 
src/main/java/com/scg/domain/Invoice.java:17: error: package com.scg.util does not exist
import com.scg.util.StateCode;
.......................//long error message
```

This means I do not have `com.scg.util.*` in my `classpath`. so I tried

```
javac -cp src/main/java/com/scg/util/*  src/main/java/com/scg/domain/Invoice.java 
src/main/java/com/scg/util/ListFactory.java:8: error: package org.slf4j does not exist
import org.slf4j.Logger;
                ^
src/main/java/com/scg/util/ListFactory.java:9: error: package org.slf4j does not exist
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
                ^
src/main/java/com/scg/util/ListFactory.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
import com.scg.domain.ClientAccount;
                     ^
  symbol:   class ClientAccount
  location: package com.scg.domain
  ................... // long error message
```

I read different articles on how `classpath` works and how to provide it in `command-line`. but when it comes to`package level structures`, I am not able to find a good tutorial on how to `COMPILE and RUN` packages. If a little help could be provided here on the propery way to `compile and run` these kind of `packages`, it will be very helpful.

[image]

Comment: see if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451211/easy-command-line-java-compile

Comment: see if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19776757/2970947

Answer (score 1):

> javac src/main/java/com/scg/domain/Invoice.java

Try this:

```
cd src/main/java
javac com/scg/domain/Invoice.java
```

Comment: without doing `cd src/main/java`, is it possible to make it work? I am just curious..Thanks

Comment: Yes, but you have to add the `-sourcepath src/main/java` option, and you're still in the wrong place to execute the program. Do it this way.

Comment: why do you say I am still in the wrong place to execute the program..?

Comment: Because `src/main/java` isn't implicitly on your CLASSPATH, but `.` is.

Comment: If you could spare a minute, kindly look at my package structure above. I have a class file in `app package`. I tried `javac app/Assignment03.java` when I am in `src/main/Java`, that did not `compile`, giving similar errors above, I also tried `javac -cp /Users/sridhar/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.5/:com/scg/domain/:com‌​/scg/util/* app/Assignment03.java,` that did not work either. please give suggestion